# How to remove line behind transparent button in CSS

Tags: html, css, button, background, transparent

How to remove line behind transparent button in CSS? See Picture Below
How to remove line behind transparent button in CSS? See Picture Below
How to remove line behind transparent button in CSS? See Picture Below
[image]

```css
.fullscreen {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                background: no-repeat url("https://www.planetware.com/wpimages/2019/10/switzerland-in-pictures-most-beautiful-places-matterhorn.jpg") center / cover;
            }
            .line {
                position: absolute;
                width: 3px;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
                top: 0;
                left: 50%;
            }
            .btn {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                border: 3px solid #ffffff;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                z-index: 1;
            }
            .btn::after {
                content: '';
                display: block;
                width: 60px;
                height: 60px;
                background: #ffffff;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }
```

```html
<div class="fullscreen">
    <span class="line"></span>
    <div class="btn"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You could try to add the image as background image to that button, but could be hard to scale it the same way as the background. Could you provide some code?

Comment: I added code you asked for

Comment: The snippet isn't working like this. 
When I change the width and height of `.fullscreen` to 100vw and 100vh it displays the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a hack and might not work for you because you didn't provide any code so far.

My idea was to give the (in my case) `.outer_box` the same `background-image` as the `.background` and scale it the same way.

```css
.fullscreen {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: no-repeat url("https://www.planetware.com/wpimages/2019/10/switzerland-in-pictures-most-beautiful-places-matterhorn.jpg") center / cover;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: no-repeat url("https://www.planetware.com/wpimages/2019/10/switzerland-in-pictures-most-beautiful-places-matterhorn.jpg") center / cover;
  background-size: 100vw;
}

.btn::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="fullscreen">
    <span class="line"></span>
    <div class="btn"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @Max You are welcome. I also changed my code to yours so it's the same example